# Independent random variables and product spaces

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-analysis

Let's say we have a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and some independent random Variables $X$ and $Y$. Then we know that $P(X+Y \le s)$ is equal to $P(\{a \in \Omega : X(a)+Y(a) \le s\})$.

Now $P_{X}$ together with the Borel sets form a measurable space, analog also with $Y$, so we construct the product space with the mass $P_{X}\otimes P_{Y}$.

The question is, how can we show that $$P(\{a \in \Omega : X(a)+Y(a) \le s\}) = P(X+Y \le s) = (P_{X}\otimes P_{Y})(\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2} : a + b \le s\})$$

The first equality is just definition, but how do we prove the second equality?

Comment: My understanding of your notation is that $P_Y:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a measure defined by $P_Y(A) = P[Y\in A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.  Then it does not make sense to write $P_Y[X+Y\leq s]$ since $\{X+Y\leq s\}$ is a subset of $\Omega$ not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Also $P_Y[\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} : a+b\leq s\}]$ does not appear to make sense or to have any connection to the problem.

Comment: "$P_X \otimes P_Y$" is a measure defined on $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{R}^2)$, not on the original probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$.  Therefore, you should drop the second equality and everything is then making sense.

Comment: @Michael didn't write $P_{Y}[X+Y /le s]$, I wrote $P[X+Y \le s]$. I understand the confusion with the notation $P_{X}\bigotimes P_{Y}(X+Y \le s)$ that's why I typed out the definition, $P_{X}\bigotimes P_{Y}(\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} : a + b \le s\})$. Maybe I should have written $P_{X}\bigotimes P_{Y}(x+y \leq s)$ instead, and by $x+y \le s$ I'm talking about a function that takes $x$ and $y$ and maps them to a real number

Comment: I think you mean $(P_X\otimes P_Y)(\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2: a+b\leq s\})$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I'm well aware of that, sorry for my confusing notation, writing out the full definition, the equality I'm having trouble with is the following : $P({a \in \Omega : X(a)+Y(a) \le s} = P_{X}\bigotimes P_{Y}(\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} : a + b \le s\})$

Comment: @Michael Yes exactly! Sorry for the confusion., I'll fix them now

Comment: @hteica As I told you, just drop the second equality, and then you got it.  It is basically a definition of the product measure, so there is actually nothing to prove.

Comment: You still need to fix it as it says $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Michael Done, thank you!

Comment: @Zhanxiong Sorry, I don't see how it follows from the definitions, it would be great if you could elaborate, thanks

Comment: Actually I think this is a deep theorem that results from something like the Caratheodory extension theorem: We have two measures $\mu_1:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $\mu_2:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow [0,1]$ that agree on the rectangular sets $\mu_1(A \times B) = P[(X,Y)\in A \times B] = P[X \in A] P[Y \in B] = P_X[A]P_Y[B]=\mu_2(A \times B)$ for all $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. The sigma algebra of this collection of rectangular sets is the same as $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ so the two measures must be the same: $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

Comment: @hteica Too long for a comment, see my answer below.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your answer, I considered that before and my only problem was how to define $\mu_{1}$, and I see that defining it as $P[(X,Y) \in A \times B]$ is probably a good idea, then we can generalize it to $\mu_{1}(U) = P[(X,Y) \in U]$ and without using the full power of Caratheodory's extension theorem we can just use Dynkin's uniqueness theorem since the base algebra is closed under intersection. Do you think this would work?

Comment: @Michael You overcomplicated the situation.  There is no need to deal with sets like $A \times B$, as the set $\{(x, y): x + y \leq s\}$ of interest is clearly given.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I've read your answer, I'm sure in the book you mentioned its already proven so you can just call the equality. But in my scripts the equality was not proven and the product measure was defined separately and the connection was not yet formally proven, so $\mu$ by definition, is simply a measure that has the separability property, in the sense that we can write $\mu[X \in A, Y\in B] = \mu_{1}[X \in A] \mu_{2}[Y \in B]$, and nothing more

Comment: @Zhanxiong : Remember the second part of Einstein's quote "Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler."

Comment: @hteica My answer is all based on your condition "Let's say we have a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and some independent random Variables $X$ and $Y$".  If you assumed the independence between $X$ and $Y$, then the distribution of $(X, Y)$ has to be the product measure $P_X \times P_Y$.  If you really read my book, it was not "proven", it is stated as "*are defined*".

Comment: @Michael Let's just stick with the problem itself.  My answer is below, which part do you think I made it "too simpler"?

Comment: @Zhanxiong : Thanks. I have now commented on your answer how I view it as too simple (ignoring the heart of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives detail on my comment: We can use a uniqueness result which is something that can be viewed as more basic than the Caratheodory extension theorem (but is along the same lines):

Lemma 1.6b: If two probability measures agree on a $\pi$-system, then they agree on the sigma algebra generated by that $\pi$-system (from *Probability with Martingales* by David Williams).

We have two probability measures:

1. $\mu_1:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow [0,1]$ is defined
   $$ \mu_1(C) = P[(X,Y)\in C] \quad \forall C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
2. $\mu_2:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow [0,1]$ is defined
   $$ \mu_2(C) = (P_X\otimes P_Y)(C) \quad \forall C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

Define $V$ as the set of all "rectangle-type" sets $A \times B \subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. It can be shown that $\sigma(V)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and that $V$ is a $\pi$-system, since the intersection of any finite number of rectangle sets is another rectangle set. Since $\mu_1(C)=\mu_2(C)$ for all $C \in V$ (recall that $X$ and $Y$ were defined as independent random variables) we must have $\mu_1(C)=\mu_2(C)$ for all $C \in \sigma(V)$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: I see your comment on Dynkin's uniqueness theorem, it is likely the same as the lemma 1.6b I quoted.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure its the same one, thanks a lot! For the sake of completeness we still need to confirm that $\mu_1$ is indeed a measure, but I think that's pretty straight-forward :)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $(X, Y)$ is a random vector that maps $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{R}^2)$.  **By definition** (e.g., see Equation (20.17) in *Probability and Measure*), the distribution $\mu$ of $(X, Y)$ satisfies:
\begin{align}
\mu(A) = P[(X, Y) \in A], \quad A \in \mathscr{R}^2.
\end{align}

Now take $\mu = P_X \otimes P_Y$, and $A = \{(x, y): x + y \leq s\}$.

Comment: What is meant by "Now take $\mu = P_X \otimes P_Y$" and how is that intended to prove anything?

Comment: @Michael Given the condition "$X$ and $Y$ are independent".  The distribution $\mu$ of $(X, Y)$ has to be $\mu = P_X \otimes P_Y$, see (20.23) from the same reference.  Unless OP used $P_X$, $P_Y$ for another meanings.  I interpret $P_X = PX^{-1}$, i.e., the marginal distribution of $X$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes that's the definition I'm using, $P_X = PX^{-1}$. But I still can't see how it follows directly from the definition, since we defined product space separately and we didn't incorporate the independence property of $X$ and $Y$ into the construction explicitly.

Comment: No. The definition of $P_X\otimes P_Y$ is not explicit and requires an existence result. For rectangle sets of type $A \times B$ it starts with $(P_X\otimes P_Y)(A \times B) = P_X(A)P_X(B)$ but the Caratheodory extension theorem guarantees this can be extended to a full measure.  Now, how do we know that extension agrees with the measure $P[(X,Y) \in C]$?  We can observe it agrees on rectangular sets of the form $C = A \times B$, and we need a uniqueness theorem to show it agrees on all other sets (including the triangle set of interest in this question).

Comment: @Michael Maybe we have different views on this.  Let me just quote what Billingsley's text:  "$X_1, \ldots, X_k$ are independent if and only if $\mu$ is product measure in the sense of Section 18: $\mu = \mu_1 \times \cdots \times \mu_k$".  You may still require me to prove the existence of product measure from the scratch (that's what Billingsley's Section 18 did).  But again, this is how we interpret OP's question differently.

Comment: The situation now is like, in my opinion, in an exam, a student used Fubini's theorem to interchange the order of a double integration and obtain a value, and he wrote "$\int\int f(x,y)dxdy = \cdots = 3$, by Fubini's theorem".  If I were the grader, I would give him full credit, because Fubini's theorem is well-known.  If you were the grader, you would take some points off, because you thought he didn't prove Fubini's theorem itself.

Comment: @Zhanxiong : But after taking off 3 points,  I would then give a bonus 3 points because the student stated "Fubini's theorem," a theorem that I like, so we would both end up giving the student full credit on the problem. =) [assuming the answer is indeed 3].